# IE 11 not playing MP4 Video ("Invalid source")

Tags: internet-explorer, video, format, mime-types, invalidation

I am currently working on a web project where I have to play multiple videos (all mp4).

The "funny" thing about it: every video plays in IE11 apart from one.
IE returns the error: Invalid Source.

Now you probably think that the video which is not playing differs from the others. But actually it doesn't. I rendered all videos with the same settings from After Effects via Adobes Media Encoder with H.264 Codec.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can resolve this problem? i had the same...

Answer (score 4):

This could be due to one of bellow reasons:

1 - FormatFactory

I used FormatFactory, setting up AAC encoding for audio and H264 for output for the mp4 format, in "High Quality and big size"

2 - If using Internet Information Services (IIS)

- Highlight Default Web Site on the left panel;
- Double-click MIME Types on the right panel;
- Scroll down the list and notice that there is no .mp4;
- On the right panel again, click Add: at the first field, write .mp4 and on the field below write video/mp4
- Click OK and you are done.

3 - video codec not supported

Get a video converter software (like Oxelon - it is free) and choose the output to be .mp4 (even is the source is .mp4). Choose the video codec to be "H264" and the audio codec to be "AAC". This will solve your problem.

Comment: no, it doesn't solve my problem, since I rendered all videos with h.264 and acc